# Nuxt SSR時のstoreの永続化が出来ない

Tags: nuxt.js

[こちらの記事](https://qiita.com/nyk510/items/d184be3724c52713ac90)のやり方を真似てやってみましたがstoreが永続化されませんでした。

具体的には、ページロード前にmiddlewareでFirebaseAuthの認証を行います。
認証時にonAuthStateChanged関数でユーザー情報を取得し、storeに格納しています。
しかし、リロード時には必ずユーザー情報がnullしか取得出来ず、認証済みでも未認証なってしまうため、リロード時にstoreの内容で認証するという仕組みです。
解決策の教授お願いします。

Comment: 「こちらの記事」が 404 になっていますので、その内容を再現などしていただけますでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

[公式](https://ja.nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-external-jwt/)を参考にすれば簡単に実装できますよ。

下記に公式をベースにFirebaseAuth用の認証画面サンプル作りましたので
参考にして頂ければと

https://github.com/Ittan888/nuxt-firebase-auth-sample